# Undefined method in controller to display associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model called `User` and a model called `Post`

I have a controller:

```
class IntrestedController < ApplicationController
  def intrested
    post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    current_user.intresteds.create(post: post)
    redirect_to post
  end
end
```

Interested Model:

```
class Intrested < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

User model

```
#created with devise
has_many :intresteds
has_many :posts, through: :intrested
```

Post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :intresteds
  has_many :users, through: :intresteds
end
```

Migration

```
class CreateIntresteds < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :intresteds do |t|
      t.references :post, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :intresteds, [:post_id, :user_id], :unique => true
  end
end
```

On the show page for the `Post` I'm trying to show all the `users` that were interested in the `post`

```
def show
 @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 @intrested_users = @post.users
end
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `users' for #<Post:0x007f8a62bc0810>
```

Here is how users click on a button to create the associations

```
<%= button_to(intrested_path, class:"btn btn-info btn-block") do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'post_id', @post.id %>
  Intrested
<% end %>
```

Comment: Just FYI, the spelling is 'interested' – you have it correct in one place in the User model but wrong elsewhere.

Comment: I can't see any obvious problem with the code as posted, it is possible you could upload to a GitHub repo for a closer look?

Comment: I accidentally made a mistake in the spelling, but other than that i can't seem to find the mistake either, when i run it in the terminal 'rails c' and check if the relation is there, the record was saved, but i can't display it?

Comment: Remove all your data from `posts`, `users` and `intresteds` table. Create new data and try again.

Comment: Gurmukh, did you restart your Rails server since you added the `users` association to `Post`? A formerly loaded version of the class `Post` might be interfering. If you are using a preloader like Zeus or Spring, make sure to stop these, too (then start again in the case of Zeus). Does that help?

Comment: Iv reset the server, reset the database but still no luck @Raffael

Comment: Iv reset the whole db but still the same error @Kumar

Comment: Maybe this is a conflict between the `user` and the `users` association. Please try and see if it works when you rename the `users` association to something else, e.g. `interested_users`  (and of course change your controller code accordingly).